# rabbitmq - detecting "idle" queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, rabbitmq-management

I'm looking for a correct way to know when queues are idle.
"idle" = no messages were published for a predefined amount of time.

How can I use the `/api/queues` (or other API) for that?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure your approach is totally correct since the statistics on the UI aren't in real-time and the value `idle` indicates the generic queue activities.

btw you can use the `idle_since` field:

```sh
$ curl -s -u guest:guest http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/myqueue | jq '.' | grep idle_since
  "idle_since": "2020-12-26 14:02:21",
```

Comment: In my case the "idle_since" field does not exist. And the state is always "active"

Comment: please read my answer, it is not `api/queues` but `/api/queues/%2F/myqueue`

Comment: It is the same, the field "idle since" does not exist. It does exist on the "normal" installation of rabbitmq on a single node,  but it does not exist on a clustered installation